# Use sensors in non-activity class, Android/Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, accelerometer

I need to be able to implement SensorEventListener in a scene class of mine, but to be set up, it seems like sensors have to use an activity class for code like this:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

And even if I did it in an activity class, I need to use the accelerometer in a scene class. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating making your class implement `SensorEventListener`, for example:

```
public class MySensor implements SensorEventListener {
   Context context;

   public InputAccelerometerEx(Context context)  {
      this.context = context;
      SensorManager manager = 
          (SensorManager)context.getSystemService( Context.SENSOR_SERVICE );
      Sensor accel = manager.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER );
      manager.registerListener( this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME );
   }

   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)  {
      // respond to sensor changes here :)
   }

   // implement remaining sensor methods here..
}
```

Now simply create an instance of the class in the `onCreate()` of your activity, for example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   MySensor sensor;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
      super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

      sensor = new MySensor( this );
   }
}
```

Of course these are just examples, you can simply add the implementation of the `SensorEventListener` to your scene class and create an instance of that in your activity instead of using a separate class.